# Make function working for a single tuple, work for a list of tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a function

```
def series_score(sailor, races_to_discard):
    places = sailor[1]
    for i in range(races_to_discard):
        places.remove(max(places))
    print(places)
    sum_of_places = sum(places)
    print(sum_of_places)
```

that modifies a tuple like this

```
sailor = ("bob", [2, 4, 1, 1, 2, 5])
```

into this by removing the highest number in the list

```
sailor = ("bob", [2, 4, 1, 1, 2])
```

how could I adapt the function to work on list of tuples like this

```
list_of_sailors = [('Clare', [3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1]), ('Bob', [2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]), ('Alice', [1, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2]), ('Eva', [4, 5, 4, 4, 5, 5]), ('Dennis', [5, 4, 5, 5, 4, 4])]
```

Comment: `for sailor in list_of_sailors: series_score(sailor, races_to_discard)` ?

Comment: What about for when there are multiple `5` in `Eva`'s list? Do you want all removed or only 1?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
for sailor,races in list_of_sailors:
     series_score(sailor, races)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just include another loop.  Here, I'm taking off the highest two numbers in every array:

```
def series_score(sailors, races_to_discard):
    for sailor in sailors:
        places = sailor[1]
        for i in range(races_to_discard):
            places.remove(max(places))
        print(places)
        sum_of_places = sum(places)
        print(sum_of_places)

print(series_score([('Clare', [3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1]), ('Bob', [2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]), ('Alice', [1, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2]), ('Eva', [4, 5, 4, 4, 5, 5]), ('Dennis', [5, 4, 5, 5, 4, 4])], 2))
>>>[1, 1, 1, 1]
   4
   [2, 2, 1, 2]
   7
   [1, 2, 3, 2]
   8
   [4, 4, 4, 5]
   17
   [4, 5, 4, 4]
   17
```

Comment: Might change this to `def series_score(races_to_discard, *sailors)` so it still works with a single sailor.

Comment: Hmm, that didn't seem to work when I made the change.  It still indexes the element of the score list, rather than the list itself.  This works for a single sailor, but it's pretty ugly...  `series_score([['Clare', [3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1]]], 2)`